# How to display .png as a frame for <h2> and <img> usig css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, sass

```css
.s-assets {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  &__block {
    height: 10vh;
    background-image: url("http://nas.gansa.pl/2019/puszczaknyszynska/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Inteligentny_obiekt_wektorowy_kopia_12.png");
  }
  &__content {
    width: 500px;
    background-image: url('http://nas.gansa.pl/2019/puszczaknyszynska/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Inteligentny_obiekt_wektorowy_kopia_12.png');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 s-assets__block s-assets__block--first">
  <?php if (have_rows('sub_first_asset')) : ?>
  <?php while (have_rows('sub_first_asset')) : the_row();
            ?>
  <div class="s-assets__content">
    <h3 class="s-assets__block-title">
      <?php echo get_sub_field('sub_sub_first_asset_title'); ?>
    </h3>
    <div class="s-assets__block-img">
      <img alt="" src="<?php echo get_sub_field('sub_sub_first_asset_img'); ?>" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile;
         endif; ?>
</div>
```

So I have to create this:
[image]

I have made acf's for h2 and img (image of bed, in this case). Then I had to export those two frames (vertical and horizontal) and place them as .png, but I can't put them ino html structure, I have to use css.
This doesn't work and I have no idea why... maybe there is something I do not understant about how css actually works?
Please be undarstaning, this is my first time I do such things.

Answer (score 0):

note the difference in html, in your html there was only one class and not in your css you were using two
example **.assets_title** and not css with sass you were getting this: **.assets.title{}**
so in html must contain two classes in the

**Modify the code below test please:**

```css
.s-assets {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  &.__block {
    height: 10vh;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoRYM.png");
  }
  &.__content {
    width: 500px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoRYM.png');
  }
}
.__block {
    height: 10vh;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoRYM.png");
}
.__content {
    width: 500px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoRYM.png');
  }
```

```html
<div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 s-assets__block s-assets__block--first">
  <?php if (have_rows('sub_first_asset')) : ?>
  <?php while (have_rows('sub_first_asset')) : the_row();
            ?>
  <div class="s-assets __content">
    <h3 class="s-assets __block-title">
      <?php echo get_sub_field('sub_sub_first_asset_title'); ?>
    </h3>
    <div class="s-assets __block-img">
      <img alt="" src="<?php echo get_sub_field('sub_sub_first_asset_img'); ?>" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile;
         endif; ?>
</div>
```